# Error Deserializing Assembly for Dynamically Compiled codes

Tags: vb.net, .net-assembly, binary-deserialization

Am attempting to Serialize a dynamically generated/compiled assembly to store into SQL and then subsequently extract the assembly for use.  However, I am hitting an error that is driving me nuts.

"*Could not load file or assembly '<random code>, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*"

When I try to De-Serialize the Assembly. Will appreciate any pointers. Partial codes:

```
    '--------------------------------------------------------------
    'This section SUCCESSFULLY Compile & Execute the Dynamic Code
    '  vsResult returns ok.
    '  **Note: This is partial code to create the compiler.
    '--------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim voCompileResults As System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults = voCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(voCompilerParams, sb.ToString)
    Dim voAssembly As Reflection.Assembly = voCompileResults.CompiledAssembly
    Dim voInstance As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(voAssembly.GetType("libARules.clsMyRoutine"), {New libARules.Sys.clsInterProcessData(New System.Xml.XmlDocument), New libArrowOps.clsDBAccess})
    Dim vsResult As String = voInstance.GetType().InvokeMember("Run", Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, voInstance, Nothing)

    '----------------------------------------------------
    'Attempt to Serialize the Assembly for store/forward
    '----------------------------------------------------
    Dim voMemStream As New IO.MemoryStream
    Dim voBF As New Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
    voBF.AssemblyFormat = Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple
    voBF.Serialize(voMemStream, voCompileResults.CompiledAssembly)

    '--------------------------------------
    'Reset the MemoryStream position to begining
    '--------------------------------------
    voMemStream.Position = 0

    '--------------------------------------
    'Attempt to De-Serialize the MemoryStream back to an assembly
    '--------------------------------------
    voBF = New Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
    voBF.AssemblyFormat = Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple
    voAssembly = voBF.Deserialize(voMemStream)
    '----- **Error Here** ---------------------------------
```

**ERROR At this point:** at the line `voAssembly = voBF.Deserialize(voMemStream)`

*Could not load file or assembly '...<random code>..., Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. **The system cannot find the file specified**.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured it out after a nap ... Documenting it here for "future generations" :P

Apparently, I **should not** be Serializing/De-Serializing the CompiledAssembly.

```
    '-----------------------------------------------------
    'Instead of Generating in Memory, generate it into a temporary Assembly file (I don't need the CompiledAssembly from the compiler).
    ' Note: Again, this is partial code, with only the important parts here.
    '-----------------------------------------------------
    voCompilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll")
    voCompilerParams.GenerateInMemory = False
    voCompilerParams.OutputAssembly = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), "deleteNow_" & Guid.NewGuid().ToString() & ".dll")

    Dim voCompileResults As System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults = voCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(voCompilerParams, sb.ToString)

    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'After the Assembly is generated, open the Assembly file and read the entire content into a byte buffer.
    'Note that this byte buffer **CAN BE STORED into an SQL BLOB field.**
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim voInstance As Object = Nothing
    Dim vsResult As String = ""
    Dim voAssembly As Reflection.Assembly = Nothing
    If Not voCompileResults.Errors.HasErrors Then
        '----------------------------------------------------------------
        'No compilation error, open and read the generated assembly file
        '  into a Byte array.
        '----------------------------------------------------------------
        Dim voBuffer() As Byte = Nothing
        Dim voFileStream As IO.FileStream = IO.File.OpenRead(voCompilerParams.OutputAssembly)
        If voFileStream.CanRead Then
            ReDim voBuffer(voFileStream.Length - 1)
            voFileStream.Read(voBuffer, 0, voFileStream.Length)
        End If
        voFileStream.Close()
        IO.File.Delete(voCompilerParams.OutputAssembly) 'Clean-up after ourselves.

        '----------------------------------------------------------------
        'Now, re-create the CompiledAssembly from the Byte array.
        '----------------------------------------------------------------
        If Not IsNothing(voBuffer) Then
            voAssembly = Reflection.Assembly.Load(voBuffer)
        End If
        If Not IsNothing(voAssembly) Then
            '--------------------------------------------
            'Instantiate my dynamically compiled class
            '--------------------------------------------
            voInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(voAssembly.GetType("libARules.clsMyRoutine"), {New libARules.Sys.clsInterProcessData(New System.Xml.XmlDocument), New libMyLib.clsMyClass})
            If Not IsNothing(voInstance) Then
               '------------------------------------------------
               'Run my dynamic code to proof that it is working
               '------------------------------------------------
                vsResult = voInstance.GetType().InvokeMember("Run", Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, voInstance, Nothing)
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

And whola... the `vsResult` is populated.  This is a proof of concept that the `CompiledAssembly` can be stored and reused later. **NOTING** that the actual temporary assembly file has been deleted before the `voAssembly` object is recreated from `voBuffer()`.